# Add a feature like one in Windows task manager?

Tags: unity, 12.10, system-monitor, task-management

I really like the System monitor in Ubuntu but there is one feature that I am missing that is in Windows Task manager. In addition to showing the processes Windows task manager also has a tab that allows you to view open windows and to edit settings.

This is more convenient than hunting for the process. Is it possible to do this in ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

## [Task Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/lxtask/)

[image: Install via the software center]

Available in **Software Center**

It does Monitor and Control the Running Processes.

For Command Line Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install lxtask
```

[image]